# How to replace the "Item URL" with given text on a nintex email

Tags: html, email, sharepoint, nintex-workflow

Hi ive been trying to figure out a way to replace the common reference "Item URL" display text so you don't get the ugly http:// link, I still want the link to function correctly just the display text has to be something like "Click here" The code I have for the email is below (the code is messy I know but I am going to clean it up after I get it working):

```
<p style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: arial">Dear User,</p>
<p><span style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: arial">A new form has been created, please click on the link below to view it.</span><br style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: arial"/><br style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: arial"/><span id="NWRTEReference1"><a class="ms-rtestate-write" contenteditable="false" onclick="selectThis(this);" href="javascript:void(0);" reftext="%7BCommon%3AItemDisplayName%7D" link="false" style="text-decoration: underline; color: red"><span style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: arial">Item Display Name</span></a></span></p>
<p style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: arial">Regards,</p>
<p style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: arial"><strong>SharePoint Team</strong></p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to do it, the "reftext" is the display name of the link (which I guessed from the start), you then need to change "link" to equal true and add a new bit after this called "reflink" this is the link that you want to go to, in my case (as im using a common variable on nintex) it was **reflink="{Common:ItemUrl}"**. Hope this helps anyone stuck in a similar situation.